# How to fetch the pod status, container ready status in grafana dashboard for kubernetes cluster in a namespace

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-variable

I am trying to use the following query:
kube_pod_container_status_ready{namespace="$namespace",pod="$pod",container="$container"}

but not sure of how to set the container variable in grafana. Need help in this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to explore -> metric browser

In `Select labels to search in` select `containter` and then select any value.

After that, metrics on the left should be updated to include only metrics that have `container` label.

In my case it will be for example: `kube_pod_container_info`

It your case, if `kube_pod_container_status_ready` has `container` label, you could use it.

Then, add variable with query:
`label_values(kube_pod_container_info, container)` / `label_values(kube_pod_container_status_ready, container)`
[image]

Comment: Thanks much @ Maciej Nawrocki

Comment: @ShikhaPriyedarshi, do you mind marking answer as correct?